# Vba loop to start A macro

Tags: vba

I have some issues with a function.

I have date in column A6 to A100
I would like to do this: for each date, copy this date and start a macro base on the date.
It only copy but thats it its not working. A y idea? Thanks

So far I have this:

```
 Sub macro1
    Dim I as variant 
    Din sheet1 as worksheet
    Dim sheet2 as worksheet 

    For I = 6 to 100
    Sheet1.cells(I,1).copy
    Sheet2.cells("A3").paste

    Call macro2

    Next i

End sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong `Sheet2.cells("A3").Paste` 
Change your code as

```
Sheet1.Cells(2, 1).Copy Sheet2.Range("A3")
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't get it. I don't understand your code actually. Where is the paste?

Comment: in the same line as copy. Read this, it will help : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760.aspx

Answer (score 0):

use some little good coding habits:

```
Option Explicit '<--| this will force you to explicitly declare each variable but will repay you with much more control over your code and save both code debugging and maintaining time

Sub macro1()
    Dim i As Long '<--| better use Long instead of Integer type

    For i = 6 To 100
        Sheet2.Cells("A3").Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value '<--| just copy values
        macro2 '<--| call macro2, no need far "Call" keyword
    Next i
End Sub
```